# Can I modify git-add's **default** hunk size?

Tags: git, addition, patch

Using `git add -p`, one can select changes to a file for staging.

One can manually change the hunk size ([Can I modify git-add's hunk size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122210/can-i-modify-git-adds-hunk-size)), but I would like to know how to change the **default** hunk size (for example to a single line).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `GIT_DIFF_OPTS` environment variable to tell Git how many lines of context it should include in a [hunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility#Unified_format) every time it has to [generate a patch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#_generating_patches_with_p).

In your case, you would say:

```
export GIT_DIFF_OPTS=-u0
```

where the `-u0` option (the short version of `--unified`) puts *0 lines* of context in each hunk, which effectively reduces it to only contain the lines that have changed.

#### Update (*2018-11-01*)

If you're *just* interested in changing the default hunk size in the output of `git diff`, you can set it in your `.gitconfig` file by using the [`diff.context`](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-config#diff-config-diffcontext) setting:

```
git config --global diff.context 0
```

Interestingly, you can also configure the number of lines to include *between hunks* with the [`diff.interHunkContext`](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-config#diff-config-diffinterHunkContext) setting:

```
git config --global diff.interHunkContext 0
```

Setting it to `0` will effectively concatenate the hunks one after the other.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Do you happen to know a reference of all possible `GIT_DIFF_OPTS` environment variables? I found very little documentation...

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't much. The only official documentation about `GIT_DIFF_OPTS` that I know of is in [Git's man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2c78628255b8cc7f0b5d47981acea138db8716d2/Documentation/git.txt#L889-L893).

Comment: I see. As it seems, `-u??` is basically the only valid setting.

Comment: Is it possible to use not environment variable but .gitconfig?

Comment: `GIT_DIFF_OPTS` affect `git commit -p` but `git config` not :(

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich True that, I didn't re-read the question propertly. I clarified it in my answer.

Comment: `GIT_DIFF_OPTS` affects `git log -p` too.

Comment: Is there a way to control this setting *only* for `git add -p`?

Comment: thanks - had a sporadic change where one hunk was a lot more than a screen full