# GIT: how to configure the hunks recognition

Tags: git, diff, config

I am investigating the the git interactive features, from which the most important for me is the hunks merging and selection. It works very good but I need the hunks to be smaller. When working with source code files, very often the hunk contains two different changes that are not related (normally a few lines apart from each other).
This is probably because git recognizes the hunks with a given configuration, like lines apart, or ammount of chars or something like that.

Is this correct, and if so, is there any way to change / reconfigure this behavior?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122210/can-i-modify-git-adds-hunk-size

Comment: Thanks pedrorijo91, not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to just plain `git diff`, the hunk context size is configurable: it is set via the `-U` option, if specified, otherwise from your `diff.context` setting, if set.  If all of those fail the default is three lines of context (both above and below).

Hence:

```
$ git config --global diff.context 1
```

reduces the diff context to one line in each direction, instead of 3.  There is also an `--inter-hunk-context` option value that you can use to fuse more hunks together (this is the opposite of what you want so I mention it only for completeness; see `diff.interHunkContext`, available in Git 2.12 and later; and see also `--function-context` aka `-W`).

However, `git add --interactive` runs `git diff-files` or `git diff-index` rather than plain `git diff`, and as [the `git config` documentation cleverly hides](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html):

> `diff.autoRefreshIndex`
>
> When using *git diff* to compare with work tree files, do not consider stat-only change as changed. Instead, silently run `git update-index --refresh` to update the cached stat information for paths whose contents in the work tree match the contents in the index. This option defaults to true. **Note that this affects only *git diff* Porcelain, and not lower level *diff* commands such as git diff-files.**

(bold-face emphasis mine).

Although this talks about the `diff.autoRefreshIndex` setting, it applies to *all* of the configurable items: `git diff` reads and obeys your configuration, but `git diff-index` and `git diff-files` and so on do not (intentionally, so that scripts, which should use plumbing commands rather than porcelain, can get the correct behavior regardless of newly added options).

What this means in the end is that if you are referring specifically to `git add --interactive`, the answer is no, or rather, not without a little bit of work.  The interactive add Perl script uses the plumbing commands, not the porcelain `git diff`, so it must obtain and use any such setting itself.  It *does* obtain and use your `diff.algorithm` and `diff.compactionHeuristic` settings, but it does *not* use your `diff.context` setting.

Making it do so is easy but requires modifying Git slightly:

```
diff --git a/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-add--interactive b/tmp/git-add--interactive
index 235fb88..ba001a1 100755
--- a/usr/local/libexec/git-core/git-add--interactive
+++ b/tmp/git-add--interactive
@@ -47,2 +47,3 @@ my $normal_color = $repo->get_color("", "reset");
 
+my $diff_context_size = $repo->config('diff.context');
 my $diff_algorithm = $repo->config('diff.algorithm');
@@ -753,2 +754,6 @@ sub parse_diff {
        }
+       if (defined $diff_context_size) {
+               my $Uarg = sprintf("-U%d", $diff_context_size);
+               splice @diff_cmd, 1, 0, "$Uarg";
+       }
        if ($diff_compaction_heuristic) {
```

(there may be a better way to set up the `-U` argument; my Perl is clumsy).  The interactive patch (or `git add -p`) mode needs this snippet added if it is to obey your `diff.context` setting.

Of course, you can simply `split` (`s`) a hunk during interactive add, as [pedrorijo91  reminded us in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419193/git-how-to-configure-the-hunks-recognition/40420650#comment68089951_40419193) linking to [Can I modify git-add's hunk size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1122210/1256452), so there's no real need for this.  It might be nice if it were included, though.

Comment: "There is also an `--inter-hunk-context` option value (with no corresponding configuration item)"... well, there is now (Git 2.12): See [commit c488867](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c488867793dc9b273c1d35746452d44afcd3d7f5) (12 Jan 2017) by [Vegard Nossum (`vegard`)](https://github.com/vegard).  
 (Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8ec68d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8ec68d1ae2863823b74d67c5e92297e38bbf97bc), 23 Jan 2017).